# How to get all checkbox values by one specified name at asp.net server-side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

How can I get the values from checkboxes that are added by JavaScript, regardless whether the checkboxes are checked or not?

These checkboxes are created by JavaScript client side, their values will represent some data which will be saved to the database. That's why I need to get at them server side.

Comment: Are they a CheckBoxList? If not, are they contained within another control? You do not have to pass the values via the URL...

Comment: @IrishChieftain at least I need to get the checkbox ids to check Checked property... this is the same as how to get their values...

Comment: No JS expert but there is a page property in 4.0 that lets you get the client id server side without anything being appended to it.

Comment: @IrishChieftain it looks like Page.Controls can return all the controls... have not done all the details yet... will see... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that these checkboxes, when created on the client side with Javascript, have a name attribute assigned so that they are submitted in the Request.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" name="mycheck" />
```

When the form is submitted, you can access the checkbox by looking at the request params as so:

```
//will probably say "on" or "checked", not sure.
string mycheckbox= HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["mycheck"];
```

Note that you will only see in the request parameters, the checkboxes that are checked off. If you create 5 checkboxes and only one is checked off, only the one checked off will be present in the Params collection

Comment: ...my question is to get ALL checkbox values... not only those that are checked off

Comment: I thought I had been clear... You won't get ALL checkboxes, you will only get the ones that are checked off. This is logical because it wouldn't make sense to submit a request with 1000 params just because you have 1000 controls on a page. But finding a workaround is trivial: put in a hidden field the total number of checkboxes that you have created so far and name them sequentially. If the hidden field has a value of 20 and you only get in the params collection checkbox5, you can assume that all other 19 boxes were not checked off.

Comment: @shrimprice There are many ways to tackle this if you put a **little bit** of effort into thinking about the problem.

Comment: i agree you are very clear, but that does not really answer my question... then you suppose I need to know how many boxes are not checked off... this does not answer my question directly either... i know my English is not as good, let me keep explaining ................................................................................................. there are always many ways to deal with one problem, I want to compare and find a best way. for example, looping through Page.Controls or using javascript to creat a hidden text input to save all the values together... which one is better then?

Comment: @shrimprice You can't loop through Page.Controls because they won't be there; as you explained, they are created on the client-side using Javascript. Page.Controls will only hold server-side controls (those that are declared with `runat="server"`). Again, there are many ways tackle this, I presented one that solves your problem. It's not the only way but it's one way. Your English is not the problem, yours is as good as mine

Comment: @IrishChieftain because these checkboxes are created on the client-side using Javascript. You won't have an instance of a Checkbox object in the code behind so that you can say `mycheckBox.Checked`. Your code won't even compile. The only way is to access the Request.Params object.

Comment: Thanks Icarus - (I had deleted a comment asking why not just loop through them server-side and grab the Checked properties)...

Comment: @Icarus I think your comment to IrishChieftain is more helpful than the answer you listed above. the information in your answer is what I already know. it is like you want me to get the answer myself by giving me some hints... but from the beginning I was trying to avoid using Request.Params because I thought there might be a totally different way. Though I do not really like your way of answering me, I got the answer. So thank you.